# Batch file to test domains

Tags: file, testing, batch-file, dns

Alright so here is the situation, i work for a web hosting company and we have a file that has all our clients domains and whatnot inside. Now some of these clients are not hosted on our servers anymore but we can't test every 180 of em manually. So i'd need to elaborate a script in batch file or something else that does a ping on all the domains and return the IP that the ping made. Is there anyway of doing this?

So i'd look like

ping www.xyz.com

if result = our.server.ip

then echo = us

else = someone else

And then put the output of all the tests into a text file or something. It needs to do this for about 180 websites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you close:

```
@echo off
setlocal

for /f %%a in (sites.txt) do (
   for /f "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%b in ('ping -n 1 -4 %%a') do (
     if "%%b" EQU "your.server.ip" (
        echo %%a - Match>>matches.txt
     ) ELSE (
        echo %%a - No Match>>nonmatches.txt   
     )
   )
)
```

Comment: I tried this and it won't output to a file, it was giving me an 'Access Denied' error, wich i fixed by adding the absolute path of sites.txt with " brackets. But it seems like it wont output

Comment: I tried giving absolute paths to the >> pipe as well, and still won't output

Comment: So after working on your script a little i changed the delims parameter and got the following results :

Comment: C:\>(for /F "tokens=1 delims=[]" %b in ('ping -n 1 -4 C:\sites.txt') do (if "%b"
 EQU "184.107.232.178" (echo C:\sites.txt - Match 1>>"C:\matches.txt" )  ELSE (e
cho C:\sites.txt - No Match 1>>"C:\nonmatches.txt" ) ) )

C:\>(if "Ping request could not find host C:\sites.txt. Please check the name an
d try again." EQU "184.107.232.178" (echo C:\sites.txt - Match 1>>"C:\matches.tx
t" )  ELSE (echo C:\sites.txt - No Match 1>>"C:\nonmatches.txt" ) )

C:\>pause
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: seems like %%a is getting sites.txt value instead of the domain name, also %%b seems to be giving the wrong value as well

Comment: Edit your post and show a few lines from your sites.txt file. I just assumed it was one site per line with nothing else in it. At least, that's how I tested it.

Comment: also, run a ping -n 1 some.site.com and post the results of that in your edited post. Be sure to add about 5 spaces before each line so it appears in a code block.